# AjaxComplete called to often

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    console.log('test');
});
```

I opened the chrome network tab and I can see only one entry (status 200).

But the console displays:

```
(28) test
```

Why is it executed this often?

Answer (score 1):

The `ajaxComplete` triggers when any `AJAX` request is completed, even if it's successfull or not.
The `200 status code` means that your request has gone right, but, as you can read in [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) that callback will fire every time an `AJAX` request has finished.

So, you could check what URL is your request redirecting to and handle only the ones that you need.

Anyway ( just a side note ) I will use the built-in `AJAX` callback function `complete`, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { data },
    complete:function(){ 
        console.log('test'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: In the networktab there is only one entry.
There is no entry with other status than 200.
console.log(settings.url) displays 28 times the same url, but it this ajax request is only sent once.

Comment: `ajaxComplete` fires every time, it could be a plugin using ajax in behind. I would suggest you to use `AJAX complete` callback, if you can

Comment: I am only able to use ajaxComplete.
Is there any possibility to check if it is the same request, maybe an id?
I can't check the url because it can be requested several times.

Comment: You could try using `ajaxSetup`

Answer (score 1):

You can check urls of these ajax'es, and handle only needed:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  console.log('Ajax request completed for: ' + settings.url);
  if ( settings.url === "ajax/test.html" ) {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " +
      xhr.responseText );
  }
});
```

Bind it only once when document ready:

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
      console.log('Ajax request completed for: ' + settings.url);
      if ( settings.url === "ajax/test.html" ) {
        $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " +
          xhr.responseText );
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I get 28 times the same url, but this ajax request is only sent once.

Comment: @phpjssql make sure you bind the handler only once

Comment: when I put $( document ).unbind('ajaxComplete'); before my code it works.
But how could I solve this problem, without unbinding existing completes?

Comment: You should bind it only once on document ready, updated answer